# combine two arrays with the same key in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello Just a newbie in php and need your help badly. I actually have two array and I want it to to combine.

```
    ['a1']=>array(
    [0]=>200,
    [1]=>300,
    [2]=>300
    ),

    ['a2']=>array(
    [0]=>100,
    [1]=>600,
    [2]=>200
    )

    ['a1']=>array(
    [0]=>gen,
    [1]=>gen2,
    [2]=>gen
       ),
    ['a2']=>array(
    [0]=>gen2,
    [1]=>gen3,
    [2]=>gen3
       )
```

I want my output to be:

```
[a1]=>(
         [gen]=>200,
         [gen2]=>300,
         [gen]=>300,
        )
  [a2]=>(
         [gen2]=>100,
         [gen3]=>600,
         [gen3]=>200,
        )
```

Thank you very much for your help

I try this code and able to get my desire result except when there is a duplicate, it doesn't show the duplicate value or if have choice if the key is duplicate, it must add the value.

Thanks again for your help.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(a1=>array(200,300,300), a2=>array(100,600,200));
$array2 = array(a1=>array('gen','gen2','gen'), a2=>array('gen2','gen3','gen3'));
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
$result[$k] = array_combine($array2[$k], $v);
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: @DevlshOne, he admitted being a newbie, let's cut him some slack.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$keys = array(0=>'gen', 1=>'gen2', 2=>'gen3');
$values = array(0=>200, 1=>300, 2=>300);
$a1 = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

**Note:** I rebuilt your arrays as you provided the `print_r()` output. But this should get you started.

Comment: Just a follow up question, what if there is a duplicate in the key that i want to show, because it just overwrite the dupplicate key. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function.

```
$array1 = array(200,300,300);
$array2 = array('gen','gen2','gen3');

$result = array_combine($array2, $array1); // $result will be your desired array
```

And you can combine this with a foreach to finish the job.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(a1=>array(200,300,300), a2=>array(100,600,200));
$array2 = array(a1=>array('gen','gen2','gen3'), a2=>array('gen2','gen3','gen7'));
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_combine($array2[$k], $v);
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Just a follow up question, what if there is a duplicate in the key that i want to show, because it just overwrite the duplicate key. I forgot this is the main reason why I cant use the combine function. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

PHP `array_combine()` would work great in this case.

```
$a1 = array(200,300,300);
$a2 = array('gen','gen2','gen3');

var_dump(array_combine($a2, $a1));
```

Function Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example:

```
 $arr1 = array(
    (0)=>200,
    (1)=>300,
    (2)=>300
    );

 $arr2=array(
    (0)=>100,
    (1)=>600,
    (2)=>200
    );

  $a1=array(
    (0)=>'gen',
    (1)=>'gen2',
    (2)=>'gen3'
       );
   $a2=array(
    (0)=>'gen2',
    (1)=>'gen3',
    (2)=>'gen7'
       );


var_dump(array_combine($a1, $arr1));
```

Tested on my localhost.

Comment: Just a follow up question, what if there is a duplicate in the key that i want to show, because it just overwrite the duplicate key. I forgot this is the main reason why I cant use the combine function. Thanks again

Comment: I'm gonna look up on your answer....just wait a little..

Comment: The whole point of array is to have unique keys....sorry